# ¿Cómo "convertir" un tipo DateTime de C# a un tipo Date de Javascript?

Tags: asp.net, angular

Necesito pasar un DateTime del backend al frontend y poder utilizar las funciones propias de Javascript como toLocaleString(), etc.

Gracias!

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta no es lo suficientemente clara ni detallada. Por favor agrega el código relevante de lo que estás intentando, puedes leer [mcve] como referencia. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para darte una respuesta mejor necesito más información.
Supongamos que estás consumiendo un end-point que te retorna un json:

```
let respuesta = {fecha: '10/2/2019 9:14:58 PM'}
```

Entonces, puedes simplemente convertir tu `DateTime` por un `TimeStamp` y tener algo así:

```
let respuesta = {fecha: '1570050062896'}
```

Y así, fácilmente puedes crear un `Date` de Javascript

```
let mDate = new Date(Number(respuesta.fecha))
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos!